# Sequelize callback before save() is finished

Tags: promise, sequelize.js, instance

here is my code:

```
//Models definition
var User = sequelize.define('user', ...);
var Address = sequelize.define('address', ...);
var Club = sequelize.define('club', ...);
//Club scopes
  scopes: {
    withUser: {
      include: [
        { model: User }
      ]
    },

//Models associations
User.hasOne(Address);
Club.hasOne(User);
Club.hasOne(Address);



//Main

//Create address
  var addressToCreate = {};
  if(body.address) addressToCreate.address = body.address;
  if(body.city) addressToCreate.city = body.city;
  if(body.zipCode) addressToCreate.zipCode = body.zipCode;

//Get user from db
  var user = await User.findByPk(body.user);


  var clubToCreate = { name: body.name, phone: body.phone };

//Persist Address in db
  return Address.create(addressToCreate)
  .then(address => {

//Persist club in db
    return Club.create(clubToCreate)
    .then(club => {

//Associate User and Address to Club
      club.setAddress(address);
      club.setUser(user);

//Save club with associated models
      return club.save()
    })
    .then(club => Club.scope('withUser').findByPk(club.id))
    .then(club => { console.log(club); return club; })
  })
```

In my db, table address contains userId and clubId and table user contains clubId;

This code seems to work to create and associate models. But the final club displayed by console.log shows user: null

However, in db there is the good row in table user with the good foreign key who reference the club id

My logs show that the request select (from Club.findByPk) is done before the update (from club.save). Like .then is executed before promise is resolved

Sry for my bad english, hope someone can help

Comment: Looks like it should work as expected. The only thing I can see that might prevent it doing so would be if `club.save()` is asynchronous but doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `async/await` but mixing it up with the older promise style based on your code that fetches Users. Below is a copy of your code in `async/await` style, although you may not need to refetch the `club` object, etc, so continue to debug.

```
const address = await Address.create(addressToCreate);
let club = await Club.create(clubToCreate);
console.log('created club', club);

club.setAddress(address);
club.setUser(user);
await club.save();
console.log('saved club', club);

club = await Club.scope('withUser').findByPk(club.id);
console.log('reloaded club', club);
return club;
```